# How to send space separated query param throw GET API in Jmeter e.g sourceId eq "fake_source_id_1"

Tags: utf-8, jmeter, uri, urldecode, jmeter-5.0

**I am making GET Api request with space separated query param string, but Jmeter encoded that string before hit.**

1. tried with HTTP Request Defaults but no use.
2. tried with url decode api but no use.

query param string =**sourceId eq "fake_source_id_1"**

```
    import org.apache.jmeter.config.Argument;

    URL url = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getUrl();
    String decoded = URLDecoder.decode(url.toString(), "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [HTML URL Encoding Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

> URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a plus (+) sign or with %20.

If you need more "formal" source of information check out ["Characters" chapter of the RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2)

> A URI is composed from a limited set of characters consisting of
> digits, letters, and a few graphic symbols.  A reserved subset of
> those characters may be used to delimit syntax components within a
> URI while the remaining characters, including both the unreserved set
> and those reserved characters not acting as delimiters, define each
> component's identifying data.

Therefore you cannot send whitespace "as is" as a part of a HTTP Request URL, you need to either tick the relevant "URL Encode?" box for the required parameter in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

[image]

Or use JMeter's [__urlencode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) if you cannot use the above approach:

[image]

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction/) article to get familiarized with JMeter Functions concept.